nvidia package not removed
I uninstalled the nvidia driver on my system:
$ sudo apt --purge remove nvidia-driver-470

But one lonely package still remains:
$ apt list --installed | grep nvidia

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libnvidia-compute-470/jammy,now 470.239.06-1pop0~1710862379~22.04~5a92c99 amd64 [installed,automatic]

If I understand correctly using apt rdepends will show if another package depends on this one:
$ sudo apt rdepends libnvidia-compute-470
[sudo] password for david: 
libnvidia-compute-470
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: libnvidia-decode-470 (= 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
  Depends: nvidia-utils-470
  Depends: nvidia-headless-no-dkms-470 (= 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
  Depends: nvidia-driver-470 (= 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
  Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-470
  Depends: libnvidia-decode-470 (= 470.103.01-0ubuntu2)
  Replaces: libnvidia-compute-470 (<< 390.25-0ubuntu2~)
  Depends: libnvidia-compute-465
  Depends: libnvidia-compute-460
  Depends: nvidia-utils-470
  Depends: nvidia-headless-no-dkms-470 (= 470.103.01-0ubuntu2)
  Depends: nvidia-driver-470 (= 470.103.01-0ubuntu2)
  Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-470
  Replaces: libnvidia-compute-470 (<< 390.25-0ubuntu2~)
  Replaces: libnvidia-compute-470 (<< 390.25-0ubuntu2~)
  Depends: libnvidia-compute-465
  Depends: libnvidia-compute-460
  Depends: nvidia-utils-470
  Depends: nvidia-headless-no-dkms-470 (= 470.239.06-1pop0~1710862379~22.04~5a92c99)
  Depends: nvidia-driver-470 (= 470.239.06-1pop0~1710862379~22.04~5a92c99)
  Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-470
  Depends: libnvidia-decode-470 (= 470.239.06-1pop0~1710862379~22.04~5a92c99)
  Depends: libnvidia-compute-430
  Depends: libnvidia-compute-465
  Depends: libnvidia-compute-460
  Depends: libnvidia-compute-455
  Depends: libnvidia-compute-450
  Depends: libnvidia-compute-440

So if I'm interpreting this correctly it's only other nvidia packages that depend on this package and there are no other nvidia packages installed, so why is it still there? Does apt miss things once in a while? Is it safe to remove this package with sudo apt remove libnvidia-compute-470?
Edit: This question is not so much about how do I uninstall nvidia drivers. It's more about why is apt behaving the way it is.

sudo apt --purge remove nvidia-driver-470

will purge the nvidia-driver-470 package, and any package which depends on it (and it will tell you what these are, if any, before doing so).
It doesn’t remove packages which nvidia-driver-470 depends on, even if removing nvidia-driver-470 means they are no longer needed. That is why libnvidia-compute-470 was left behind.
To remove packages which are no longer necessary, assuming they are marked as automatically installed (which they should be), you need to run sudo apt autoremove (or sudo apt autopurge), or specify the --autoremove option when running sudo apt remove:
sudo apt --autoremove purge nvidia-driver-470

Note that this will remove all packages which are deemed unnecessary (that is to say, marked as automatically installed but no longer depended upon), not only those which become unnecessary as a result of removing nvidia-driver-470.

To remove nvidia driver completly, use:
sudo apt --purge remove '*nvidia*470*'
sudo apt autoremove


Ok that worked to remove the package but it doesn't answer my question about why apt left the module when it wasn't being used by anything (or at least it seemed that way).
